# Extract multiple page TIFF documents and "old-style JPEG-in-TIFF" documents using JAI

Tags: jai

I am trying to Extract multiple pages TIFF documents and "old-style JPEG-in-TIFF" documents using JAI.

With the below code, I am able to extract the multiple pages TIFF document into single images but it doesn't work on old style JPEG document.

```
public void extractMultiPageTiff() throws IOException {

        filePath = (String) getSessionObject("fileName");

        if (filePath != null && !filePath.equals("")) {
            file = new File(filePath);

            SeekableStream ss = new FileSeekableStream(file);

            ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", ss, null);
            int count =  dec.getNumPages();
            TIFFEncodeParam param = new TIFFEncodeParam();
            param.setCompression(TIFFEncodeParam.COMPRESSION_GROUP4);
            param.setLittleEndian(false); 
            System.out.println("This TIF has " + count + " image(s)");
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                RenderedImage page = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(i);
                File f = new File("C:\\FilePages\\single_" + i + ".tif");
                System.out.println("Saving " + f.getCanonicalPath());
                filePages.add(i, f);
                ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
                pb.addSource(page);
                pb.add(f.toString());
                pb.add("tiff");
                pb.add(param);
                RenderedOp r = JAI.create("filestore",pb);
                r.dispose();

            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know the code changes to be made in order to extract multiple pages of both 'TIFF' and 'old style JPEG' documents using JAI 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have some sample images to share? I have written a [TIFF ImageReader plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff) that attempts to read old-style-JPEGs. It *might* read your files. Unfortunately, the spec is broken, and sample files hard to find. Having more sample files would really help!

Comment: I found a sample at this link http://www.nightprogrammer.org/wp-uploads/2013/02/multipage_tiff_example.tif

Comment: When I debugged the above code, the file which I am reading has compression = 1 and the decoder and encoder from stream are "tiff". Then why does it throw 'decoding of old style JPEG not supported' error. Could you please list the steps to use your plugin. Thanks.

Comment: You should find everything you need in the [readme, see installing](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#installing) especially. My plugin reads the file you linked just fine, however, all pages in it has compression 7 ("new" JPEG). I.e.: This is not the file you are looking for.